# How to use Requester Pays in AWS Glue Visual Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

We have databases stored in another department's aws account we want to use as a source to build a glue job within the same company. I can access their databases and query just fine in athena as I believe we set up some sort of cross-account access. When I try to use glue studio visual, I get an user role error when running the job which I'm assuming is because we aren't indicating we want to pay the cost of querying the data. The reason I say this is because if I add the lines of code below (requester pays header), the glue job executes without an issue:

```
glueContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.useRequesterPaysHeader","true")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.useRequesterPaysHeader","true")
```

Unfortunately, I can only run the glue jobs when I create a glue job in script mode only. I'm not as well versed on the coding side and was hoping to use Glue Visual to create my jobs. My question is how can I use Glue Visual and get around this error by somehow indicating yes we are okay with paying for it?

EDIT: I can't go to script view after making the visual job and add the code below in as AWS won't let me go back to visual mode after that